# Display page views count in K and M format in php

Tags: php

I created a page_views_count script in php to display the page views count in K format.

The script bellow is working but it doesn't give expected result.

This is the script :

```
 <?Php
$views=1060;
if($views > 1000)
{$views_count=$views *1/1000; 
 echo "$views_count k views";}
else{echo $views;}
```

This script  shows views count  this way :

```
 999  = 999 page views 
 1050= 1.05 k page views
 1060 =1.06 k page views 
 2300= 2.3 k page views
```

I want it to show the Results in following format :

```
 999  = 999 page views 
 1050= 1 k page views
 1060 =1.1 k page views 
 2300= 2.3 k page views 
 2354= 2.4 k page views
```

Does someone know how to solve this? Any help on this issue would be much appriciated.

Kind Regards!

Starkeen.

Comment: Why do you expect this `1050= 1.5 k page views` ?

Comment: Assuming that was a mistake, try `round()`

Comment: @Daan sorry that was a typo, updated the post

Comment: If it weren't a typo, `round($views_count,1,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)` would work ;)

Comment: i would recommend to not do `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` so 1050 should be 1.1k like everybody would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP  [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function and [PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) constant solved my problem.

```
 <?Php
 $views=1060;
 if($views > 1000)
 {$views_count=$views *1/1000; 
 $views_k=round($views_count,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
 echo "$views_k k views";}
else{echo $views;}
?>
```

**Output :**

```
 999  = 999 page views 
 1060= 1 k page views
 1160 =1.2 k page views 
 2300= 2.3 k page views 
 2354= 2.4 k page views
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/358215)

Hope this helps someone in future.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will work for you! Updated Code

```
function countViews($num) 
{
    $units = ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T'];

    for ($i = 0; $num >= 1000; $i++) {
        $num /= 1000;
    }

    return round($num, 2) . $units[$i];
}
```

You can use the function like :

```
<?php 
  echo countViews(1000);
  // output 1k
?>
```